# Constructing window based on message timestamps in Spark DStream

Tags: apache-spark, sliding-window, dstream

I'm receiving DStream from Kafka and I want to group all messages in some sliding window by keys.

The point is that this window need to be based on timestamps provided in each message (separate field):

```
Message structure
--------------------------
key1, ..., ..., 1557678233
key1, ..., ..., 1557678234 
key2, ..., ..., 1557678235
```

So, I want to consider messages where for each key `timestamp of the first message` - `timestamp of the last message` <= 5 minutes

As I can see from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571416/spark-window-function-with-synthetic-timestamp), that's not feasible since Spark counts only system time for events. The guy over there suggests using `updateStateByKey`, which is not very clear for me...

Maybe we could achieve this using another approach?

What about including timestamp's differences in `combiners` for `combineByKey` function with further summation & filtering by durations threshold?

Please add your thoughts on that, or share your solution if you had a chance to face the same problem...

Thanks!

Comment: Why bother with legacy?

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible? Without a doubt. [Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/), which among others, provides [Apache Spark backend](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark/) can easily handle such operations.

However that's definitely not something you want to implement yourself, unless you have significant development resources and a lot of know-how at your disposal. And if you had, you probably wouldn't ask this question in the first place.

Handling late events, out-of-order events, and recovering from node failures can be tricky at best, with larger number of edge cases.

Furthermore it would be obsolete before you actually implement it - `DStream` is already considered a legacy API, and is likely to reach it's end-of-life sooner rather than later. At the same time [Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) can already handle event time windowing out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with below sample data and I assume timestamp is in epoch format -

```
[key1, ..., ..., 1557678233]
[key1, ..., ..., 1557678234]
[key2, ..., ..., 1557678235]
[key2, ..., ..., 1557678240]
[key2, ..., ..., 1557678271]
[key3, ..., ..., 1557678635]
[key3, ..., ..., 1557678636]
[key3, ..., ..., 1557678637]
[key3, ..., ..., 1557678638]
[key3, ..., ..., 1557678999]
```

//-- create udf to return if record needs to be processed or rejected

```
scala> spark.udf.register("recordStatusUDF", (ts:String) => {
     |     val ts_array = ts.split(",",-1)
     |     if ((ts_array.max.trim.toLong - ts_array.min.trim.toLong) <= 300) {
     |        "process"
     |     }
     |     else { "reject" }
     | })
res83: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,StringType,Some(List(StringType)))
```

//-- Create schema

```
scala> val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("key", StringType, true),StructField("col2", StringType, true),StructField("col3", StringType, true),StructField("epoch_ts", StringType, true)))
schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(key,StringType,true), StructField(col2,StringType,true), StructField(col3,StringType,true), StructField(epoch_ts,StringType,true))
```

//-- Create Dataframe

```
scala> spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema).createOrReplaceTempView("kafka_messages")


scala> spark.sql(s""" select x.key, recordStatusUDF(x.ts) as action_ind from ( select key, concat_ws(",", collect_list(epoch_ts)) as ts from kafka_messages group by key)x """).createOrReplaceTempView("action")

scala> val result = spark.sql(s""" select km.* from kafka_messages km inner join action ac on km.key = ac.key and ac.action_ind = "process" """)
result: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [key: string, col2: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> result.show(false)
+----+----+----+-----------+
|key |col2|col3|epoch_ts   |
+----+----+----+-----------+
|key1| ...| ...| 1557678233|
|key1| ...| ...| 1557678234|
|key2| ...| ...| 1557678235|
|key2| ...| ...| 1557678240|
|key2| ...| ...| 1557678271|
+----+----+----+-----------+
```

you can use above code on each rdd (kafka messages). Hope this is helpful.